# How to configure SOLR for stemming

Tags: solr, solrj, stemming

I am learning solr and using solr-5.3.0. I want to include common stemmers in solr. I followed this [Tutorial](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Advanced-Fulltext-Search-Configuration). But after making changes to the schema.xml when I search for a term I didn't get desired output. ALso, there are many `schema.xml` and I am not sure which one to edit.

```
{
"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
        "indent": "true",
        "q": "HOLIDAY",
        "_": "1441115332479",
        "wt": "json"
    }
},
"response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "name": [
                "A lovely winter holiday"
            ],
            "_version_": 1511117845476409300
        },
        {
            "id": "1235",
            "name": [
                "A lovely summer holiday"
            ],
            "_version_": 1511118023312801800
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

when I search for `holidays` it didn't give any result. I added this in `schema.xml`.

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: which configuration is been used by you for your core...?

Comment: I have added a core named `new_core`  in core admin.i didn't specify anything else regarding configuration.

Comment: I am a newbie in solr. Started just today.

Comment: did your index text has the word "holidays"..? because if I tried it in the solr analysis tool and it got the match...I thought "PorterStemFilterFactory" is causing the issue but it doesnt seems so..

Comment: After the schema change - you did re-create your index, right? Cause you nearly always need to throw it away and create it new when changing the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with below fieldType ....

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: I need to edit these changes in the schema.xml ? But, there are many schema.xml files.Also, while creating core when i try to give a different name for schema.xml , nothing gets created.

Comment: no I dont think so you need to do any change in your schema file...I thought your fieldType is not correct. so I removed "PorterStemFilterFactory". But I tried with PorterStemFilterFactory in solr analysis tool and it seems fieldType is fine. My question is did you used the solr analysis tool?

Comment: No , i didn't use solr analysis tool. I am querying from the `Query`

Comment: PorterStemFilterFactory helps to to removes common endings from words...example lovely to love.... and you have used the same in index and query. So I dont see there is any issue

Comment: try the analysis tool by accessing http://localhost:8983/solr...if you have core created http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name

Comment: In Analyse Fieldname / FieldType there is no entry of type : `text` , which i added in the schema.xml.

Comment: did you see text_en" fieldType... have a look at this tutorail you will get basic idea ...http://yonik.com/solr-tutorial/

Comment: Yeah, Now I am searching in analysis tool,but the fieldtype name `text` is not present there.

Comment: i checked in types `text_en` is there.

Comment: ok...did you tried by adding field value for index and query...check the same